# What does "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" mean?

Tags: c, pointers

Earlier, I asked a similar question, but I've since changed my code. Now the compiler gives me a different warning. This is an example of what my code looks like now:

```
void *a = NULL;
void *b = //something;
a = *(int *)((char *)b + 4);
```

When I try to compile, I get "warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast." What does this mean, and what should I do to fix it?

To clarify, I don't want 'a' to point to an address that is 4 bytes greater than 'b' (i.e., a != b+4). In my program, I know that the value stored at ((char *)b + 4) is itself another pointer, and I want to store this pointer in 'a'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, "the value stored at `((char *)b + 4)` is itself another pointer", simply add an explicit cast to the result:

```
void *a = NULL;
void *b = //something;
a = (void*)*(int *)((char *)b + 4);
```

Since you're assuming that `sizeof(void*)==sizeof(int)`, the code is not portable, but I am sure you already knew that.

A portable alternative is to use `intptr_t` instead of `int`.

Comment: This (and the entire question) is undefined behaviour, though.

Comment: @KerrekSB: No doubt about that.

Comment: @KerrekSB: What do you mean? Which part of the question leads to undefined behavior?

Comment: @David: Treating a random pointer as `int*` and dereferencing it does, i.e. the second asterisk on the third line of the answer. This is only OK if `b` was obtained by subtracting 4 bytes from an existing `int*`, but in general it's UB.

Answer (score 1):

So there's a pointer value stored at `b+4` which you want to load into `a`? Then treat it as one, and so (b+4) points to a pointer - pointer to a pointer to int is `int**`.:

```
  *(int**)((char*)b+4)
```